# Identification of duplicate pairs of values, when then their order is reversed

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

In

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(LETTERS[1:6], "A"),
                 B = c(rev(LETTERS[1:6]), "F"))
```

how can i count the amount of rows, which  are not unique? The function needs to identify reverse order pairs.

In the example above, there arent any unique letter combinations (3 x A/F; 2 x B/E, 2 x C/D), so the answer is "0".

(Letters can be replaced by any string of characters or factor levels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order the rows first (with `sort`), and then count (with `table`). I use `paste0(x, collapse = "")` to make a unique string out of the ordered pairs of values.

```r
(tab <- table(apply(df, 1, \(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))))
# AF BE CD 
#  3  2  2 

sum(tab == 1)
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Rowwise sort then check if duplicated:

```
x <- cbind(pmin(df$A, df$B), pmax(df$A, df$B))
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "F" 
# [2,] "B"  "E" 
# [3,] "C"  "D" 
# [4,] "C"  "D" 
# [5,] "B"  "E" 
# [6,] "A"  "F" 
# [7,] "A"  "F" 

df[ !(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
# [1] A B
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score -1):

First comment: "AF" in your setup appears indeed two times...

If you want to know how many non-unique rows appear you could count the number of rows, the number of unique rows and substract (here giving "1" as result)

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(LETTERS[1:6], "A"),
                 B = c(rev(LETTERS[1:6]), "F"))
nrow(df)   # returns 7, number of rows
nrow(unique(df))  # returns 6, number of unique rows
result <- nrow(df) - nrow(unique(df))  # returns 1, number of non-unique rows
```